# Property not recognized in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, routes, thymeleaf

I want to create a link in Thymeleaf to route the user to an edit page. My Java class looks like this(without getters and setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agencies")
public class Agency {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
    private String email;

    private String address;
}
```

I also have a controller with this method:

```
 @Autowired private AgencyService service;

    @GetMapping("/agencies")
    public String showAgencyList(Model model) {
        List<Agency> agencies = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("agencies", agencies);

        return "agencies";
    }
```

And this is a part of the code in Thymeleaf:

```
 <th:block th:each="agency : ${agencies}">
        <tr>
          <td>[[${agency.name}]]</td>
          <td>[[${agency.email}]]</td>
          <td>[[${agency.address}]]</td>
          <td>
            <a class="h4 mr-3" th:href="@{'/agencies/edit/' + ${agency.id} }">Edit</a>
            <a class="h4" th:href="@{/agents}">Choose</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </th:block>
```

Now everything works fine, except that in the path `th:href="@{'/agencies/edit/' + ${agency.id} }` it says **cannot resovle agency**, **cannot resolve id**. Why is that? The table is correctly displayed and I can't figure out why agency seems unknown when providing the path to another view in Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whitespace between `${agency.id} }` create problem.

**Change**

```
th:href="@{'/agencies/edit/' + ${agency.id} }"
```

**To**

```
th:href="@{'/agencies/edit/' + ${agency.id}}"
```

OR

```
th:href="@{'/agencies/edit/{id}(id = ${agency.id})'}"
```

Comment: The whitespace did not solve the error, but the second path specifying method did. Thanks!